# loginExpirationInDays using Minutes

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

How can i set the expiration token from days to minutes?

I want to set the expiration token to expire in 15minutes.

```
Accounts.config({
    loginExpirationInDays: 900000 //15 minutes this dont work
});
```

Is there a way to achive this?

Answer (score 1):

If someone also runs into this ... try this:

```
Accounts.config({
    loginExpirationInDays: (1 / 24 / 60) * 15
});
```

*Background:* The configuration `loginExpirationInDays` seems only to be used at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/8005532f4ba847d3e8bb4c1100d09bf53136ff0a/packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js#L217 where it's simply multiplied by `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` to get it to milliseconds.
If you now want to take it to 15 minutes, you could set it to the result of `(1 / 24 / 60) * 15`.

**EDIT:** The lowest value I got working was `0.05`, which is 1 hour and 12 minutes ... It doesn't kick out the user but only prevents a re-login (f.e. by reloading the page). Please vote at https://github.com/meteor/meteor-feature-requests/issues/119 for smaller values.

**EDIT2:** I guess `loginExpirationInDays` was thought for something different. Please read the PR before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because the `loginExpirationInDays` is in days and not in seconds. So your session will only expire after 900000 days!

I think there is no option to get this expiration time in minutes or seconds. 
The only way I see is to store the last activity of the user and force the logout after x minutes on server side. 
It appears that there is a package for this: https://github.com/recursivefaults/meteor-session-timeout

Comment: You think that editing the package accounts will be a good solution here?

Comment: Never tried, maybe there is a way to redeclare a variable to set a new value.